# Attach USB device of a VM programmatically

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, api, com

I'm a test developer and I work in a company that develops its own hardware. Now I've encountered a problem while testing connectivity via USB with the HW.
There is a brief summary of the test (tests) and the problem:

**Test(s) description:**

- Tests are automated
- Tests run in a VM (OS Windows 10, VM is run by Oracle VirtualBox virtualization tool)
- By the design, the tests are run directly from VM
- In the test, the tested HW is restarted

**Problem description:**

- After a restart is executed the VM detach USB from devices
- While the next test execution the detached USB device causes it's not possible to connect with the HW

To solve this problem **I need to automatically (programmatically) attach USB device of a VM within the tests are run**. I found there is a COM library part of Oracle VirtualBox virtualization tool.
Thanks to well and clear description of the library (provided on official website) using the library looks simple.

Obviously it's not possible to control a VM directly from the VM itself, so **I need to figure out how to make the VM to communicate with a hosting machine. The host will then attach USB device after the reset is executed.**

****My questions are:****

***A) Is there anyway how to reattach a device on a VM?***
***B) What would be the simplest way how to use COM (Component Object Model) of a host machine?***

Comment: In the settings of each VirtualBox VM on the "USB" tab you can create a device filter for USB devices that are automatically redirected into the VM once the are attached to the host computer. There is also a tab for forwarding COM ports into the VM.

Comment: I finally managed how to make USB to be still attached (I needed to removed it from UBS filters and then add it again). But the connectivity between the HW and a VM is not still working until I reattach it to the VM. I looked into Device Manager and there is a USB device described as "Unknown USB device (port restart failed)". When I reattach the device to the VM the unknown device disappears and connectivity with the HW is working.

Comment: In my experience, the USB functionality of VirtualBox is very fragile. If you manage to get it work with reattaching the device, then using a software switchable USB hub (enable/disable ports via software) may be an option for you. See this project for details: https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl

Comment: I've looked at the project you've provided and it seems the tool is only compatible with Linux 
, but there is a Win OS running on the VM. I tried disabling and enabling the USB port using devcon utility but it didn't help.